# Linearisation of a structured-population model with a nonlocal nonlinearity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-operators, linearization

I would like to linearise the following differential operator (which is the McKendrik-von Forster equation combined with a nonlocal nonlinearity):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial n(t, x)}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial g\big(I(t), x\big)n(t, x)}{\partial x} &= \mu(I(t), x)n(t, x) && t > 0, x \in \Omega \subset R, \\
I(t) &= \int_{\Omega} \gamma(x)n(t, x) \, dx,
\end{align}

where the first equation is the advection at speed $ g $ of individuals of size $ x $ at time $ t $, $ \mu $ is a loss rate, and $ I $ is the nonlocal nonlinearity. The function $ \gamma $ represent a weight, i.e., the influence of a particular $ n(x, \cdot) $ on the rates $ g $ and $ \mu $.

I would like to linearise this operator around a solution $ \tilde{n} $, but I am not sure how to start. If I rewrite $ g $ as a function of $ n $ only, then I can follow what is done on this page: [How do you "linearize" a differential operator to get its symbol?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677181/how-do-you-linearize-a-differential-operator-to-get-its-symbol/1677219?newreg=e7d3e79c33374e79ae37e20ce218405e). However, I have the feeling that this is not correct to do it this way because the nonlinearity is nonlocal.

Should I instead compute $ I $ for a perturbed solution ($ \varepsilon $ as small as I wish):
$$
n = \tilde{n} + \varepsilon v
$$
and therefore
\begin{align}
I(t) &= \int \gamma \tilde{n} \, dx + \varepsilon \int \gamma v \, dx \\
     &= \tilde{I}(t) + \varepsilon I_v(t)
\end{align}
and then develop $ g $ around $ \tilde{I} $ as:
$$
g\big(I(t), x\big) = g\big(\tilde I(t), x \big) + \varepsilon I_v(t) \partial_I g(\tilde I, x)
$$
and then continue the calculus with the differential operator keeping only terms of order 0 and 1, and dropping all the $ \varepsilon^2 $ terms? I guess at the end I will get the same equation with $ v $ instead of $ n $, with few $ \tilde n $, and this equation should be linear in terms of $ v $. So can anyone confirm which path I should take and if what I am thinking is correct (I assume that the functions are all nice, I am not asking about the existence of a solution).